# Search multiple files listed in a text file and copy to another directory

Tags: windows, search, cmd, command

I need to find a number of 120 image files, of which names I have listed in a text file (a single filename per line). The search is to be done in all subfolders of an external HDD and all files are to be copied to local drive.

I think it would be a variation on this command line:

```
 FOR /F "delims=" %N in (C:\Users\me\Desktop\files.txt) do COPY "%N" C:\Users\me\Pictures\found
```

but when I run it, I think it only searches in given directory, without subdirectories.

How should I modify that command?

Comment: Change `COPY "%N" C:\Users\me\Pictures\found` to something else which isn't just copying a file from the current directory!

Comment: I thought this bit defines the target directory?

Comment: `C:\Users\me\Pictures\found` defines the target directory, yes, but you're not having trouble with that, your issue is the source file allocated to `%N`. The variable `%N` is just the filename from the file, so `COPY` needs to know where the file is before it can copy it, otherwise it only looks in the current working directory. You want to look inside every directory/subdirectory of a drive, not just the current working directory so you need to modify your methodology to take account of that. Use the site search to find examples of locating files recursing directory trees.

Comment: OK, thank you. Will look into it.

Comment: Since I was looking specifically for images, I used XN View instead to look for the files. It's not a batch search like I wanted, though.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %N in (C:\Users\me\Desktop\files.txt) do COPY "%N" C:\Users\me\Pictures\found
```

uses just "%N", so the filename from the current folder. If you want to search it "down the folder tree", you have to look for it:

```
    FOR /F "delims=" %N in (C:\Users\me\Desktop\files.txt) do for /r %M in ("%N") do  COPY "%M" "C:\Users\me\Pictures\found\"
```

Be prepared for possible duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Since this was a search for images, I used XnViewMP and took my time to let it comb through ~20gb of images, and copied the relevant images. Not ideal, but job done.